# Can not get CSS file

Tags: node.js, express

My directory is set up like this:

```
app.js
views     
  home.html
  css
    style.css
```

My home file is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

My app is like this:

```
var io   = require('socket.io'),
    url  = require('url'),
    sys  = require('sys'),
    express = require('express'),
    http=require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var socket = io.listen(server);

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(4000);
sys.puts('server running ' + 'now ' + Date.now());
```

The problem is that when I run the app, the CSS file can not be loaded.

Comment: Is this directory also in this structure on your webserver where you are running you code ?

Comment: im not quite sure your question

Comment: You are running your code on a server or ? and the structure of your directories, is it the same at the webserver ?

Comment: I'm developing the app locally

Comment: Why `<style>`? why not `<link>` tag?

Comment: Yeah you are doing it wrong its <link href="css/style.css"> and not <style href="css/style.css>

Comment: it's a typo, my code is actually link

Comment: Is your server handling the `static css` file and outputting the `home`? what happens when you visit the css file directly?

Comment: Did you misname your directory folder as `vews`? Or was that just a typo upon writing this?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Since .css files are static files you have to serve them to the clients. However, you do not serve static files as a express middleware. Add the following middleware to your express app and move the `css` folder under the `public` directory (you should create a `public directory`)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

So your final directory structure should look like this

```
app.js
views
  home.html
public
  css
    style.css
```

And do not forget to require `path` module

```
 var path = require('path')
```

Comment: Will this work with `body-parser` module? And can I use multiple `express.static` paths?

For example one for public (.html files) and one for styles (.css files)?

Comment: we can use `path.resolve` as well `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));`

Answer (score 6):

In one of my apps, I have these relevant files in this file structure:

```
/
index.js
  /public
    /stylesheets
      main.css
  /views
    /partials
      header.ejs
```

The `index.js` includes `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`
Note the `/public`.

The header.ejs partial includes `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/main.css' />`
Note the lack of public, it’s implied by the middleware.

In your example, your current directory for static files doesn’t match where you are keeping static files.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

This might solve the problem.

Comment: why downvote? this solved my problem. should use `/css/style.css` instead of `css/style.css`

Comment: @dgknca This doesn't answer the actual question, it answers a different question. See the file tree given.

Comment: The express.js framework handles the HTTP requests, so it should know where the static files for the Web app are located. By default there is no such folder.

Use `express.static`. Read about it here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: This worked, thansk

Comment: Hey mate sorry for judging, this answer worked.  upvoting this answer.